# Why use column probability in finding the nash equilibrium, when the row's action's payoffs are considered to be equal?

Tags: game-theory

In the example shown below, we consider that expected payoff of both the row's action will be the same. While calculating the expected payoff of the action we use the probability of the column, shouldn't we also consider the probability of the row action, whose payoff we are calculating?

[image]

Comment: What does x,y mean in the matrix? (p.ex. (2,1) in the upper left corner)

Comment: Player 1's action is on row and player 2's action is on column. (2,1) here means that 2 is the payoff for player 1 to choose B as his action and 1 is the payoff for player 2 choosing B as his action.

Answer (score 0):

In equilibrium, every player must play a best response. Randomising between two pure strategies is a best response only if the player is indifferent between them.

Why? Think of it as tossing a coin to decide what to do as Player 1. If you like B strictly more than F, tossing a coin is not a best response because you might end up with F and miss out on B (which you like better).. But if you are indifferent between B and F, whatever the coin says you end up with the same utility.

Precisely because you are indifferent between B and F, you are also indifferent whether the coin is fair or biased. Even if B is more likely to be chosen, you always end up with the same utility. So the probability of the row action affects the likelihood that you play B or F, but it is irrelevant for your utility.

On the other hand, the probabilities of the column action must be finely balanced to make sure that you are indifferent.

Comment: How do we mathematically represent indifference between two actions in this case?

Comment: Indifference reads $u_1(B,p) = u_1(F,p)$ where $p$ is a shortcut for Player 2 playing $B$ with probability $p$ and $F$ with probability $1-p$. This gives exactly the equation on the second to last line in the slide of your OP.

Comment: I get the point that the utilities should be the same. But I am not able to understand, while calculating the  u1(B,p), shouldn't it be equal to: P1(B)*(2p + 0(1-p)), since we are fixing the action B, and calculating its expected utility.

Comment: What is P1(B)? A probability?

Comment: Yeah, P1(B) is the probability associated with the action B of player 1.

Comment: OK then the answer is that you fix B, so you are *sure* to play B as a pure strategy. You are computing the expected payoff of playing B for sure against a randomising opponent.

Comment: I guess you haven't completely understood my question. So in the problem in the image, we need to find a strategy, which is a probability distribution for nash equilibrium. So we fix some probabilities with player 2 and say that the utilities of player 1 will be equal. So we equate those two utilities. So while calculating u1(B) we multiply p to 2 and (1-p) to 0. But shouldn't this whole be multiplied to P1(B) (that is how expected utilities are calculated). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Sorry, but you are wrong. The two cases under consideration when computing expected utility are $(B,B)$ with probability $p$ and $(B,F)$ with probability $1-p$. Player 1 is **not** randomising. Moreover, if he would be randomising, you should include in the computation the case where he plays $F$.

Comment: OK I get it, but on what basis are we assuming that player 1 is not randomising, I believe it is nowhere related to the utilities being the same.

Comment: @Ruckus: let us move beyond comments/slides. Any decent textbook in game theory has an explanation.

Comment: Perhaps this may be useful to you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828806/why-you-randomize-your-opponents-payoff-in-a-mixed-nash-equilibrium/828817#828817